# Genymotion Emulator Error With Expo

Tags: android, emulator

Hello dear all stack expertise.

How are you? Hope! you all are doing good. I am having little bit trouble with Genymotion emulator with expo.

The error message is below. Please read it carefully and please solve my problem as soon as possible.

"Couldn't start project on Android: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048) could not read ok from ADB Server * failed to start daemon * error: cannot connect to daemon"

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?